# how to find active connection in cassandra, for example in Mysql "SHOW PROCESSLIST"

Tags: cassandra, datastax

how to find active connection in cassandra for Datastax,
for example in Mysql "SHOW PROCESSLIST" so i want to get number IP uses  current database in cassandra. i do google but no command found.